# how can i find this html file in WordPress project

Tags: php, wordpress

I just received this WordPress  project in work  and i have little experience in WordPress, i need to edit title and button because it has wrong URL link but i cant find where this this page is in the project.
this is how the page looks from inspect :

````
```<html lang="en-US" class="no-js"><head>``
    <!-- keywords -->
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <!-- viewport -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <!-- profile -->
    <link rel="profile" href="https://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
    <title> big tag company</title>
````

and this is the page in the project :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?> class="no-js">
    <head>
        <!-- keywords -->
        <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
        <!-- viewport -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
        <!-- profile -->
        <link rel="profile" href="https://gmpg.org/xfn/11" />
        <?php wp_head(); ?>
    </head>
    <?php
    $litho_custom_attr_body = '';
    
    if ( function_exists( 'litho_custom_attr_helper_obj' ) ) {
        ob_start();
        litho_custom_attr_helper_obj()->attr( 'body' );
        $litho_custom_attr_body = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
    }
    ?>
    <body <?php body_class();?> <?php echo sprintf( '%s', $litho_custom_attr_body ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped ?>>
    <?php
        if ( function_exists( 'wp_body_open' ) ) {
            wp_body_open();
        } else {
            do_action( 'wp_body_open' );
        }

        get_template_part( 'templates/header/header', 'wrapper' );
```

it seems like it is in get_head() function ? if thats right how can i find this function please ?

this is tamplate/header.php file :

````
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying the main header builder
 *
 * @package Litho
 */

// Exit if accessed directly.
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

$litho_data_sticky_column       = '';
$litho_nav_class                = array( 'header-common-wrapper', 'header-img' );
$litho_enable_header_general    = litho_builder_customize_option( 'litho_enable_header_general', '1' );
$litho_enable_header            = litho_builder_option( 'litho_enable_header', '1', $litho_enable_header_general );
$litho_header_section_id        = litho_builder_option( 'litho_header_section', '', $litho_enable_header_general );

/* Main header section */
if ( 1 == $litho_enable_header && ! empty( $litho_header_section_id ) ) {
    
    $litho_header_sticky_type       = get_post_meta( $litho_header_section_id, '_litho_header_sticky_type', true ); /* Header sticky type */
    $litho_template_header_style    = get_post_meta( $litho_header_section_id, '_litho_template_header_style', true ); /* Header style */

    $litho_template_header_style    = ( ! empty( $litho_template_header_style ) ) ? $litho_template_header_style : 'standard';
    $litho_header_sticky_type       = ( ! empty( $litho_header_sticky_type ) ) ? $litho_header_sticky_type : '';

    $litho_nav_class[]              = $litho_template_header_style;
    $litho_nav_class[]              = 'navbar';

    switch ( $litho_template_header_style ) {
        
        case 'standard':
        default:
            $litho_nav_class[] = 'navbar-expand-lg';
            
            if ( ! empty( $litho_header_sticky_type ) ) {
                $litho_nav_class[]  = $litho_header_sticky_type;
            }

            if ( 'no-sticky' != $litho_header_sticky_type ) {
                $litho_nav_class[] = 'fixed-top';
            } 

            break;
        case 'left-menu-classic':
        case 'left-menu-modern':
            $litho_nav_class[]          = 'header-left-wrapper';
            $litho_data_sticky_column   = ' data-sticky_column';
            break;
    }
}

$litho_header_wrapper_class = apply_filters( 'litho_main_header_wrapper_class', $litho_nav_class ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped
$class = ( is_array( $litho_header_wrapper_class ) ) ? ' ' . implode( ' ', $litho_header_wrapper_class ) : '';
?>
<nav class="<?php echo esc_attr( $class );?>"<?php echo esc_attr( $litho_data_sticky_column );?>>
    <?php
        if ( current_user_can( 'edit_posts' ) && ! is_customize_preview() && ! empty( $litho_header_section_id )  ) {
            $edit_link = add_query_arg(
                array(
                    'post'        => $litho_header_section_id,
                    'action'      => 'elementor',
                ),
                admin_url( 'post.php' )
            );
        ?>
        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $edit_link ); ?>" target="_blank" data-placement="right" title="<?php echo esc_attr__( 'Edit header section', 'litho' ) ?>" class="edit-litho-section edit-header litho-tooltip">
                <i class="ti-pencil"></i>
        </a>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
    <?php do_action( 'theme_header' ); ?>
</nav>```
````

Comment: You won't find a whole page as a "file", the WP templating system consists of multiple levels of template files.

Comment: And the page title is not hardcoded anywhere, put output dynamically. If you want to manipulate it, you should look into the WP _filter_ system; `wp_title` would probably be the one to use here.

Comment: title in WordPress can change from site settings, also most of WordPress template (idk which template you currently using), give this ability to change the button style in their THEME OPTION section.

Comment: ok for the title but how can i find the button ? it has wrong URL

Answer (score 0):

Please go to wp-content->themes->current activated theme directory->templates->header->open header.php file

Comment: couldn't find it , i added template/header.php file to the post can u check it please?

Comment: Ok thank you for addition please share website URL and which title and button you want to edit(share the screenshot please)?

Comment: https://hamorabi.moch.gov.iq/ ..... the black button in the center of the page please

Comment: That black button you mean? please see the screenshot https://ibb.co/W0J04S9

Comment: @Muhammed yes bro

Comment: ok please open https://hamorabi.moch.gov.iq/ then on top you can see any "Edit with Elementor option"?

Comment: if yes then click on that please

Comment: can we speak on private please?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).